# ViewController disable interaction - iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I decided to collect data from users. And I started adding viewController on the top of mainViewController as also shown in the image below.
My problem is that user could able to interact mainViewcontroller, which mapKit in my case.Whenever user scrolls picker view, it also affects mapViewController at the button!

I dont want user to be able to interact with the mainViewController.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `userInteractionEnabled = NO` on the map view?

Comment: Are you using an overlay instead of an independent view controller? If the view controller for your popup was created properly and properly handles the touch events, the events should not be propagated to views above/before it in the hierarchy. Perhaps you could set the popup to be first responder and not allow it to resign first responder status until dismissed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to take a screenshot of the mainViewController view and use that image as the background to your gender and age collection view. That would have the advantage of only requiring a single view controller to be displayed, perhaps conserving memory.

Answer (score 4):

You could disable user interactions of the `mainViewController` when the overlay is shown, as follows:

```
mainViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: once user picks up his age, and I want to move to another viewController, what would be the best way to do it?